# Safe to get &std list item?

Tags: c++, list

Is it safe to do the following?

```
std::list<Something> someList;

...
someList.push_back(Something(8));
Something* something = &someList.back();
```

I would think it is safe but I'm not completely sure.

Thanks

Comment: Even though that's valid code, if you're using raw pointers to reference things in C++ you might want to consider a different mechanism, such as using an iterator or a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the object will be valid until you erase it from the `someList`. See [Iterator Invalidation Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules) for information about when the objects can get destroyed for various container operations.

Comment: Yes, hardly anything will invalidate a pointer or reference to a `list` element.